# When using a keyListener in Flex, how do I catch a keystroke with Alt+S?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, keylistener

I am using a combination of actionscript and MXML. I have my listener established but am unable to discern how to capture the keystroke of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> for my web-app.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple: use `altKey` on the [KeyboardEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/KeyboardEvent.html):

```
private function onKey(evt:KeyboardEvent):void {
    if (evt.altKey && charCode == 83) {
        trace("Alt-S pressed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Be aware that it is very important what has the focus when inside a browser. You will only get `KeyboardEvent`s after the first click into your application (then the flashplayer "is active" aka "has the focus"). And I experienced that, depending on the browser, some key combinations have still been "taken" by the browser and are not delivered to the flash player.